# Make a function take a subsequent parameter each time?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to draw 3 stacks of rectangles, where each stack consists of the number of blocks represented by the second value in each sublist (**6**, **2** and **9**)

```
from turtle import *

myList = [[1, 6], [2, 2],[3, 9]]

def rectangles(num_layers):
    for x in myList:
        num_layers = x[1]

        pendown()
        color('Black', 'Aquamarine')
        begin_fill()
        setheading(180)
        forward(220)
        setheading(90)
        forward(50)
        setheading(0)
        forward(220)
        setheading(270)
        forward(50)
        end_fill()
        penup()
        setheading(90)
        forward(50)

for y in myList:
    if y[0] == 1:
        goto(0,0)
        rectangles(myList)

    elif y[0] == 2:
        goto(300, 0)
        rectangles(myList)

    elif y[0] == 3:
        goto(600, 0)
        rectangles(myList)
```

however instead of 3 stacks of 6, 2 and 9 respectively I'm getting 3 stacks of 3. My issue comes from a lack of understanding for the comprehension of lists and loops. I need my function to take the second number from each list, and construct a stack of that many rectangles then move to the next location, read how many in the next stack and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my rework of your code based on what your turtle appears to be doing:

```
from turtle import *

myList = [(1, 6), (2, 2), (3, 9)]

def rectangles(num_layers):
    for _ in range(num_layers):
        pendown()

        begin_fill()

        for _ in range(2):
            backward(220)
            right(90)
            backward(50)
            right(90)

        end_fill()

        penup()

        right(90)
        backward(50)
        left(90)

setup(950, 550)
color('black', 'aquamarine')
penup()

for y, x in myList:
    goto(300 * (y - 1) - 225, -200)
    rectangles(x)

mainloop()
```

You should try to use relative turns like `left(90)` instead of absolute turns like `heading(90)` when possible as it makes your program more flexible (think rotation.)

> a lack of understanding for the comprehension of lists

There are no list comprehensions in your code so you might want to reread about those.

[image]